# What is Yui feeling just by looking at her eyes?

Tags: mitsuboshi-colors

What do Yui’s eyes suggest she is feeling when they are like that? This scene is from the last episode of Mitsuboshi Colors, which just finished airing this week. Her eyes are like that while Sat-chan is interviewing her mother.

[image]

Comment: Usually [empty eyes](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/EmptyEyes), but I don't know if it applies here since I don't know about the anime at all.

Comment: Sat-chan and her mother were in a spiral of excessive mutual complements so empty eyes fit